# Do we have more primes of the form $3k+1$ or of the form $3k+2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let us denote by $a_{1}(n)$ the number of prime numbers in the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which are of the form $3k+1$.

Let us denote by $a_2(n)$ the number of prime numbers in the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which are of the form $3k+2$.

My questions are:

> 1) Do we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_1(n)}{a_2(n)}=1$?
>
> 2) If the limit in the question 1 is not equal to $1$ is it known what is the value of the limit?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: @Element118 Thank you.

Comment: So by the wiki article question 1) limit is 1, not 1/2. That is, roughly same number of primes of each type as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @coffeemath I do not know why I wrote $\frac {1}{2}$ because I was thinking about $1$ and instead wrote $\frac {1}{2}$. I will edit the question so that the question describes what I thought and not what I wrote.